# How to extract postal code before checkout on WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to extract the postal code indicated by the customer in the basket to be able to calculate his shipping costs?

Note that I have just created an extension for the database and some more management. So I want to add this feature from this extension

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJlyE.png)

I've already tried just about everything I could find, such as this code :

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'cwpai_get_customer_postcode');

/**
 * Get customer postcode after shipping calculation
 */
function cwpai_get_customer_postcode() {
    // Get the customer's shipping address object
    $customer_shipping_address = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address();

    // Check if the customer has a shipping postcode
    if (isset($customer_shipping_address['postcode'])) {
        // Store the customer's shipping postcode in a global variable
        global $cwpai_customer_postcode;
        $cwpai_customer_postcode = $customer_shipping_address['postcode'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you able to get the postcode from `WC()->customer`? If yes, is this postcode really stored as a global variable that you can access from another function? How do you do your shipping calculations based on a postcode, and where is that calculation code? what does mean *"Note that I have just created an extension for the database and some more management. So I want to add this feature from this extension"*? Edit your question please, if you want to have a chance to get helped.